# Salt cured egg yolk storage life

Tags: eggs, storage-lifetime, curing

Does anyone know long would salt cured salted egg yolks keep in the refrigerator?

I've seen a few articles including this one https://practicalselfreliance.com/salt-cured-egg-yolks which notes that its good for about "3-4 weeks if not longer", though some claim that it's only good for about 2 weeks.

Is there anyone here who could clarify which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you will store them ( individually wrapped, in a plastic box, vacuum sealed ?)

It can also depend on how dry is your fridge.

It also depends on how dry they are.

I'd say 2 weeks max; [some say](https://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/cured-egg-yolks) 1 month or [more](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/salted-egg-yolks).

The [Egg farmers of Canada](https://www.eggs.ca/recipes/recipeideas/99/how-to-make-salt-cured-egg-yolks-and-other-creative-egg-recipes) advocacy group doesn't even say.

Don't make couple of dozen of them if you don't intend to use them relatively quickly or have access to vacuum seal equipment.

IMO, it's easy to cure 3, 4 yolks at a time and use them in that time span.

Anecdotal, I've kept vacuum sealed yolks (each one in its own little vacuum bag) for a couple of months with not issues.

(speaking of which I should do some today)

Comment: I usually keep them in an airtight container and my fridge is pretty dry though I'm kinda liking the idea each yolk having its own tiny bag. Also how'd you know if the yolk is still good, I don't see mold nor smell any funkiness so I'm usually more worried if there are other things I should look out for.

I have a pretty strong stomach but I'd have to consider these things when serving to guests